# Is there is a C# function which is similar to .Map() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, linq

Hi I have some background in Javascript, and I used `.filter()` and `.map()` a lot, recently I have a c# project, I am new to c# just wondering is there a C# function which is similar to `.Map()`in JavaScript? I know that `.where()` is very similar to `.filter()`.

btw `.map()` is like

```
    const newArray = array1.map(
          el => {
                if(el.id===1){
                el.name='foo';
                return el;
                 }
               return el;});
```

and it returns a new array. `.FroEach()` does not return a new array.

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: The equivalent is [.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can Use `.Select()`:

```
array.Select(el =>
    {
        if(el.id == 1)
        {
            el.name="foo";
            return el;
        }
        return el;
    }
);
```

Comment: There is no `===` in C# this won't compile.

Comment: copy paste did it to me again